# Multi Threading WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

Still learning MVVM and multi-threading and have come across something I cannot figure out.

Users access a list of applicants via a Datagrid for their specific branch location.  They can click a button within the datagrid to obtain SelectedItem to open a more detailed view of that application.

The initial time they open this view, the data is correct; however, any further time(s) they open the view the original data is still shown.  It does not show the second applicants information in the View unless the application is closed and opened again.

I have read that the ViewModel is stored in memory and I thought, maybe threading would provide a solution.  I used the following code to attempt just that; however, no luck.

Can someone please point me in the correct direction on how I can handle this situation, or if I am approaching this totally wrong.  :)

Thank you for your time.

```
private void NewWindowHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID = Convert.ToInt32(appIDTextBox.Text);

            Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                Window tempWindow = new Window
                {
                    Title = "Display Applicant",
                    Content = new Craig_Tools.ApplicationTrackingSystem.userControls.atDisplay(),
                    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                    //ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
                };

                tempWindow.Show();
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            newWindowThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error opening Applicant Display");
        }
    }
```

I have also tried the following.

```
  private void NewWindowHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID = Convert.ToInt32(appIDTextBox.Text);

            //create and show window
            atDisplay newView = new atDisplay();
            ViewModels.displayViewModel viewModel = new ViewModels.displayViewModel();
            newView.DataContext = viewModel;    
            newView.Title = "Applicant ID: " + Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID;

            newView.Show();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error opening Applicant Display");
        }
    }
```

What I have figured out using Visual Studio debugger is that the ViewModel is never executed when attempting to open the information for the second applicant.  It seems to simply just grab the data that is in memory.

Comment: When you're having trouble with values of things not being what you expect, threading is the exact opposite of a solution. It's like, beyond opposite. It's like turning 180 degrees up to 11.

Comment: What is 'appIDTextBox' and what is its relationship with the DataGrid? We'd also need to see what your Craig_Tools class is doing (especially the implementations of Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID and Craig_Tools.ApplicationTrackingSystem.userControls.atDisplay, since these apparently must be sharing some state).

Comment: appIDTextBox is a text box on the initial display that has the application ID assigned to it when an item is selected in the datagrid.

Comment: Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID is just a globally available integer that I can assign the application ID to for retrieving on other views.  In this case, when they select the button to view the detailed application view, it assigns the appID to Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID.

Comment: Craig_Tools.ApplicationTrackingSystem.userControls.atDisplay is the View.

Comment: Your first approach is setting `Content`, not the `DataContext` of either `UC` or `Window` and in the second it appears that `atDisplay` is  a `Window` now? **Remove Threading** you don't need it. make sure you `atView` assigns new `DataContext` when initialised and your `ViewModel` triggers `INotifyPropertyChanged`. TBH more info about `UC` and `VM` would be usefull. BTW if you reply make sure you use '@' symbol and my nickname otherwise I **won't** get notified. HTH

Comment: @XAMIMAX Yes, I converted the UC into a Window in an attempt to determine what was causing the issue.  I have removed the threading and now just have the code to open the window. (Edited Above)  When I open view for Applicant A, then close, and then open View for Applicant B, it is still showing data for Applicant A.

Comment: I just figured it out.  The global reference I was using was not repopulating when I would open the view a second time.  I removed the variable for the application ID on my ViewModel and just had every instance of it pull from the global path of 'Craig_Tools.Data.Globals.selectedAppID' every time it needs it.